# regex javascript - match multiple search terms ignoring their order

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to find all the matches of given strings (divided by spaces) in a string.
(The way for example, iTunes search box works).

That, for example, both "*ab de*" and "*de ab*" will return true on "*abcde*" (also "*bc e a*" or any order should return true)

If I replace the white space with a wild card, "ab*de" would return true on "*abcde*", but not "de*ab".
[I use * and not Regex syntax just for this explanation]

I could not find any pure Regex solution for that.
The only solution I could think of is spliting the search term and run multiple Regex.

Is it possible to find a pure Regex expression that will cover all these options ?

Comment: *Why?* This isn't really something regex was designed to do, so why are you trying to shoehorn it into regex? Just search individually for each of the strings.

Comment: Why does `ab*de` match `abcd`? Where's the `e`? Also, should the pattern `ad de` also be valid on the given phrase `ad hominem` (since `ad` is found)? What's the meaning of the asterix: Should all preceding non-whitespace characters be matched, or just the preceding character?

Comment: @Amber : I was just thinking that pure Regex would be faster. I use this search to filter results on the fly for a dropdown. So it has to be fast.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't any pure-regex solution for this. `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems.` - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @Rob W: my mistake. I fixed my question (it was "ab*de" in "abcde").
And yes "*" means all non-whitespace characters should be matched.

Comment: @Ranch 1. What does `*` *exactely* mean? Any character (one, or even none?). 2. What does the space mean? All / at least one of the characters, any order?

Comment: @Ranch - Have you actually tried it and seen that regular approaches aren't fast enough? Computers are fast fast fast. In any case, if you are having performance issues with it the solution is likely indexing/caching, not regex (which for all its optimization isn't all that fast)

Answer (score 9):

Returns `true` when all parts (divided by `,` or `' '`) of a `searchString` occur in text. Otherwise `false` is returned.

```
filter(text, searchString) {
    const regexStr = '(?=.*' + searchString.split(/\,|\s/).join(')(?=.*') + ')';
    const searchRegEx = new RegExp(regexStr, 'gi');
    return text.match(searchRegEx) !== null;
}
```

Comment: **Nice idea!** Upgraded from @RoccoC5 answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809030/7514010 - I think you better change the `.*` to `[^]*` to it support new lines too. And using `RegExp.prototype.test()` is more accurate. Example: https://regexr.com/67ldq Just logically and tested, for big strings like a paragraph it is **low performance**

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you could come up with a regex to do what you want, but it may not be the most efficient approach.

For example, the regex pattern `(?=.*bc)(?=.*e)(?=.*a)` will match any string that contains `bc`, `e`, **and** `a`.

```
var isMatch = 'abcde'.match(/(?=.*bc)(?=.*e)(?=.*a)/) != null; // equals true

var isMatch = 'bcde'.match(/(?=.*bc)(?=.*e)(?=.*a)/) != null; // equals false
```

You could write a function to dynamically create an expression based on your search terms, but whether it's the best way to accomplish what you are doing is another question.

Answer (score 4):

Alternations are order insensitive:

```javascript
"abcde".match(/(ab|de)/g); // => ['ab', 'de']
"abcde".match(/(de|ab)/g); // => ['ab', 'de']
```

So if you have a list of words to match you can build a regex with an alternation on the fly like so:

```javascript
function regexForWordList(words) {
  return new RegExp('(' + words.join('|') + ')', 'g');
}
'abcde'.match(['a', 'e']); // => ['a', 'e']
```

Comment: That's called an *alternation*.  A *conditional* is more complex ([ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)).

Comment: this is a nice approach , but it will return true when either of the words ('ab' OR 'de') will be in the matched string. I want it to return true only if both 'ab' AND 'de' found.

Comment: Then check if both 'ab' and 'de' are found in the matches array?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var str = "your string";
str = str.split( " " );
for( var i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++ ){
    // your regexp match
}
```

Comment: Well, I was asking if there's a pure Regex solution...guess not

Comment: `i` and `c` haven't been declared. That aside, why are you checking `c` against an array? Split will always return an array, containing one element if no character is found, or zero elements if the string is empty.

Comment: @RobW You're right. Damn, totally didn't notice... Edited now.

Comment: `str.split( " " )` creates an array even if there aren't any spaces in the str

Comment: @qwertymk that's why the answer was edited 5 minutes before your comment =)

Comment: huh `str = str.indexOf( " " ) != -1 ? str.split( " " ) : [ str ];` is `===` to `str.indexOf( " " )`

Comment: Since I want to check that ALL of the words in str are found. 
We can stop the loop when at least one word is not found.

Answer (score 2):

This is script which I use - it works also with single word searchStrings

```
var what="test string with search cool word";
var searchString="search word";
var search = new RegExp(searchString, "gi"); // one-word searching

// multiple search words
if(searchString.indexOf(' ') != -1) {

    search="";
    var words=searchString.split(" ");

    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        search+="(?=.*" + words[i] + ")";

    }

    search = new RegExp(search + ".+", "gi");

}

if(search.test(what)) {

    // found

} else {

    // notfound

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are matching words, or parts of words. You want space-separated search terms to limit search results, and it seems you intend to return only those entries which have all the words that the user supplies. And you intend a wildcard character `*` to stand for 0 or more characters in a matching word.

For example, if the user searches for the words <kbd>term1 term2</kbd>, you intend to return only those items which have *both words* `term1` *and* `term2`. If the user searches for the word <kbd>term*</kbd>, it would match any word beginning with `term`.

There are suitable regular expressions which are equivalent to this search language and can be generated from it.

A simple example, the word `term`, can be asserted in regex by converting to `\bterm\b`. But two or more words which must match in any order require lookahead assertions. Using extended syntax, the equivalent regex is:

```
(?= .* \b term1 \b )
(?= .* \b term2 \b )
```

The asterisk wildcard can be asserted in regex with a character class followed by asterisk. The character class identifies which letters you consider to be part of word. For example, you might find that `[A-Za-z0-9]*` fits the bill.

In short, you might be satisfied if you convert an expression such as:

```
foo ba* quux
```

to:

```
(?= .* \b foo            \b )
(?= .* \b ba[A-Za-z0-9]* \b )
(?= .* \b quux           \b )
```

That is a simple matter of search and replace. But do be careful to sanitize the input string to avoid injection attacks by removing punctuation, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be barking up the wrong tree with RegEx. What you *might* want to look at is the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of two input strings.

There's a Javascript implementation [here](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/levenshtein.js) and a usage example [here](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/).

Comment: This is not what he's looking for. The demo shows `apple pear` and `pear  apple` (with two spaces) as having the same distance as `apple pear` and `pear orange`...