# is there any way to search in table and show multiple connected tr

Tags: html, jquery, html-table

I would like to make a list of youtube videos just like its design.

I am finding trouble to make a search option for it, ie when  a user search name of that video then whole tr connected to it show up.

Can this be achieved using jquery? My code for search only searches tr and it doesn't show connected tr. I would like to have a search option just like youtube does.

Below is the code that I am working with

```js
$(".filter").change(function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).val();
  var row = $('.row');

  row.hide()
  row.each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).attr('data-type') == filterValue) {
      $(el).show();
    }
  })

});

$(document).ready(function() {

  (function($) {

    $('#filter1').keyup(function() {

      var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
      $('.searchable tr').hide();
      $('.searchable tr').filter(function() {
        return rex.test($(this).text());
      }).show();

    })

  }(jQuery));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="filter1" type="search" placeholder="Search "></form>

<Br>
<label for="filter">Show videos of specific Category:</label>
<select class="filter" data-tableId="table1">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="music">Music </option>
  <option value="art">art</option>
  <option value="dance">dance</option>
</select>


<table id="table1">
  <tbody class="searchable">
    <tr class="row" data-type="music">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">Music 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" data-type="music">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" data-type="music">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" data-type="music">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : Music  </span></td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="row" data-type="art">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">art 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" data-type="art">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" data-type="art">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" data-type="art">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : art </span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row" data-type="music">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">dance 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" data-type="dance">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" data-type="dance">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" data-type="dance">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : dance  </span></td>
    </tr>



</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start. You need tbody for each song

I changed from the data-type on each row to a class on each tbody

I also used code from

[regex javascript - match multiple search terms ignoring their order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808783/regex-javascript-match-multiple-search-terms-ignoring-their-order)

to make a regex with orderless seach

```js
const find = () => {
  let val = $('#filter1').val();
  val = val.replace(/[^\w]/g," ").replace(/\s+/g," "); // normalise the string
  var reString = '(?=.*' + val.split(/\s/).join(')(?=.*') + ')'; // (?=.*party)(?=.*dance) any order
  console.log(reString)
  var rex = new RegExp(reString, 'gi');
  var category = $(".filter").val();
  var selector = '.searchable' + (category ? "." + category : "");
  $('.searchable').hide();
  $(selector).filter(function() {
    return rex.test($(this).text());
  }).show();
};

$(function() {
  $(".filter").change(function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    $('.searchable')
      .each(function(i, el) {
        let found = false;
        if ($(el).hasClass(filterValue)) {
          found = true;
        }
        $(el).toggle(found || filterValue === "");
      })
    find();
  });
  $('#filter1').on("input", find);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="filter1" type="search" placeholder="Search "></form>

<Br>
<label for="filter">Show videos of specific Category:</label>
<select class="filter" data-tableId="table1">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="music">Music </option>
  <option value="art">Art</option>
  <option value="dance">Dance</option>
</select>


<table id="table1">
  <tbody class="searchable music">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">Music dance video party song</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : Music  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="searchable art">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">art 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : art </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="searchable dance">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">dance 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : dance  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="searchable dance">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">dance 2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 16-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : dance  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sir a little clarification.can this search be extended to search inside category.What I meant is if a user select "art" category and "art" category has many videos,now when they search then do the search of videos inside that selected category not inside all videos.Can this be possible with this code.Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Please see update. It is rather extensive :) It will now keep the category in mind but also allow change of category while keeping the text in the filter1

Comment: Thanks you so much sir. I got what I wanted.Thanks again

Comment: . May I ask one more thing.I came to know that the my  search function is very poor for eg: video name =" dance & play " if a user search " play & dance " it doesn't list. Is there any way to modify search which makes search to match kerwords regardless of its order in arrangement .Thanks

Comment: , ie It only checks whether user typed words are there in video name or not without checking arrangement.

Comment: Can you ask a new question with this and post an example with proper titles to search? There are ways to do this. If you have & in the text please explain if you need the & to be ignored

Comment: No ,I don't need "&" to be included. Another eg: Video name :" dance song  party ".  This video should list if user type "song dance party" , "party dance song" and "party song dance" .It should match the words regardless of its arrangement in video name. Sir  should I need to post it as new question or can you answer here . Thanks.

Comment: Sir,When you get time .Please respond to his query.It is related to above asked question . Thanks    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676177/changing-add-to-favourites-functions-from-tr-to-tbody

Comment: Why do you have a new user id?  that is confusing

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the select, you have to make sure that you show all when `all` is selected, and also you can simplify the `show()` with a specific selector:

Regarding the search by text, I would search in each cell with the title (you have used the class `a2`).

Also, I would create an element that wraps every item. Now you have several top-level `<tr>`s that belong to the same item. I would make one `<tr>` per item and then several `<td>`s for each field (thumbnail, title, date, etc.) I just used a `<tr>`, but you can use `<tbody>` if you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {

$(".filter").change(function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).val();
  var $rows = $('.row');

  if (filterValue === 'all') {
    $rows.show();
  } else {
    $rows.hide();
    $(".row[data-type='" + filterValue + "']").show();
  }
});

$('#filter1').keyup(function() {
  var filterText = $(this).val().trim();
  var $rows = $('.row');

  // make sure that the filter of the select box is applied
  $(".filter").change();

  if (filterText === '') {
    // do nothing
  } else {
      var rex = new RegExp(filterText, 'i');
      $('.searchable .a2').filter( function () { return !rex.test($(this).text().trim()); } )
                          .closest('.row')
                          .hide();
  }
});

  }(jQuery));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="filter1" type="search" placeholder="Search "></form>

<Br>
<label for="filter">Show videos of specific Category:</label>
<select class="filter" data-tableId="table1">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="music">Music </option>
  <option value="art">art</option>
  <option value="dance">dance</option>
</select>


<table id="table1" class="searchable">
  <tbody class="row" data-type="music">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">Music 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : Music  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="row" data-type="art">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">art 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : art </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="row" data-type="art">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">art 2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : art </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="row" data-type="dance">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">dance 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : dance  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="row" data-type="dance">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">dance 2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : dance  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But Sir.it destroys the layout . see these two pics.
Your code seems like  : https://i.postimg.cc/8zQK62xg/Capture.png
What i want: https://i.postimg.cc/g0pTfCKH/3.png

Comment: Functionality comes first, design later :) I edited the answer.

Comment: your code works perfect for me.Thanks. May I ask little clarification.I came to know that the search function is very poor for eg: video name =" dance & play " if a user search " play & dance " it doesn't list. Is there any way to modify search which makes search to match kerwords regardless of its order in arrangement .Thank you so much for spending time for me

Comment: ,  ie It only checks whether user typed words are there in video name or not without checking arrangement. –

Comment: For that, you have to it manually. Split by space, remove words without letters/nums, like "&", probably remove also words only one or two characters long, and check if each title contains at least one of the words.