# Changing "Add to Favourites" functions from <tr> to <tbody>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got code for a bunch of books arranged in  which has favourite button against each tr

Here is the code that I got

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function(e) {
    const $parentTable = $(this).closest("table");
    $(this).find('img.white-star').toggle();
    $(this).find('img.yellow-star').toggle();
    const $favs = $("tr").has('img.yellow-star:visible');
    $parentTable.prepend($favs)
    const favs = $favs.find("td:first").map((i, fav) => $(fav).data("id")).get();
    //localStorage.setItem($parentTable.attr("id")+"favs",JSON.stringify(favs)); // uncomment this on server
  })
  let favs // = localStorage.getItem($(".ratingTable").attr("id")+"favs"); // uncomment when on your server
  // favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : []; // uncomment when on your server
  favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : ["Book A", "Book C"]; // remove this after testing
  $.each(favs, function(i, fav) {
    $("table tr td[data-id='" + fav + "']").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().trigger("click")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  height: 25px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ratingTable" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book A">Magic by dalton</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book B">The chair by Jhon</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book C"> Book C</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am currently trying to make a site similar to youtube.I would like to have above Rating option to be added to list of videos.Below is code that I am working with

I would like to have this: when user click rating I want not only the tr of video name to be saved but all tr & td under that tbody should be selected and saved to localstorage & retained when refreshing the page but in book listing only tr is selected and saved . I hope you get it.

Can Rating or Add to favourite button migrated from tr to tbody .Any help is  appreciated. Thanks

```css
.white-star,
.yellow-star {
  height: 25px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.ratingTable {
  width: 400px;
}

td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

td[data-id] {
  width: 300px;
}

#table1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="Music">
  <tbody data-id="Video-A" class="searchable music">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">Music </a></td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <div class="fav">
          <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
          <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : Music  </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">Music </a></td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <div class="fav">
          <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
          <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : Music  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="Art">

  <tbody data-id="Video-B" class="searchable art">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">art 1</a></td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <div class="fav">
          <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
          <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : art </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="Art">
  <tbody data-id="Video-D" class="searchable dance">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">dance 1</a></td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <div class="fav">
          <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
          <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : dance  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why u  need to move from tr to tbody? any reason?

Comment: @Vishal Pawar    Please see  question again.I updated it.Does that clarify what you asked sir ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You need all entries in a separate tbody and all tbodies in the same table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change td to tbody everywhere

and change to this

```
 $("table tbody[data-id='" + fav + "']").each(function() {
```

NOTE: You cannot have more than one thing in each tbody for this to work and ALL tbodies have to be in the same table

- `$(".fav").on("click",clickIt)`  change to `const $tbody = $(e.target).closest("tbody");`
- remove `find("tbody")` in the map
- Restore needed `<table class="ratingTable" id="videorating">`

Complete code

https://plungjan.name/SO/bookrating/vidrate.html

```js
const clickIt = (e) => {
  const $tbody = $(e.target).closest("tbody");
  console.log($tbody.data("id"))
  const $parentTable = $tbody.closest("table");
  $tbody.find('img.white-star').toggle();
  $tbody.find('img.yellow-star').toggle();
  const $favs = $("tbody").has('img.yellow-star:visible');
  $parentTable.prepend($favs)
  const favs = $favs.map((i, fav) => $(fav).data("id")).get();
  //localStorage.setItem($parentTable.attr("id")+"favs",JSON.stringify(favs)); // uncomment this on server
};

$(function() {
  $('.fav').click(clickIt)
  let favs // = localStorage.getItem($(".ratingTable").attr("id")+"favs"); // uncomment when on your server
  // favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : []; // uncomment when on your server
  favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : ["Video-A", "Video-D"]; // remove this after testing
  $.each(favs, function(i, fav) {
    $("table tbody[data-id='" + fav + "']").each(function() {
      $(this).click()
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  height: 25px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ratingTable" id="videorating">
  <tbody data-id="Video-A" class="searchable music">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a">Video-A: <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">Music </a></td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <div class="fav">
          <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
          <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : Music  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-id="Video-B" class="searchable music">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a">Video-B: <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">Music </a></td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <div class="fav">
          <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
          <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : Music  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-id="Video-C" class="searchable art">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a">Video-C: <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">art 1</a></td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <div class="fav">
          <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
          <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : art </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-id="Video-D" class="searchable dance">
    <tr class="row">
      <td rowspan="4" class="a">Video-D: <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{youtube video code }}/default.jpg" alt="" /></td>
      <td class="a2"><a href="{{LINK to Yotube video}}">dance 1</a></td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <div class="fav">
          <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
          <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">  Date : 15-Apr-20 </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Length : </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="b"><span class="child">Category : dance  </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sir,I tested it after adding ".ratingTable" and an id to table tag but it doesnot work to me.I checked localStorage of Chrome.It doesn't save.Please see this https://i.postimg.cc/50BrGLVG/aa.png. Further I am getting little issue,it is being rated when I click tbody not the td  having rating div.I have given external link to video,but if I click anywhere on tbody it is being rated.I can't click the external link of that video.It will be very helpful if It is rating after clicking td containing rating option or div with class fav.thanks again

Comment: I can understand sir.It's Ok.I will try to learn it from somewhere else. Anyway Thanks for your efforts and time spent for me.I am marking this as solved

Comment: @DavidBecckam I fixed all issues I think: https://plungjan.name/SO/bookrating/vidrate.html

Comment: I don't know how I should express my gratitude towards you.Thank you so much for your efforts