# Is there a javascript method to recognize a string even if the words are out of order?

Tags: javascript, string, methods

My goal is to get a string, when I search for words which appear in the string.
The string should also be output if the words do not appear in the order in which they are in the string.

I used the includes() method.
But if I search for two words out of order I got false.

```
let string = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
let search = string.includes("world Hello");
if (search){
  console.log(string)
}

console.log(search)
```

Comment: Use a regular expression instead? Or split up the search string and use `every`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38694640/752527 
 Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fxvuogh8/